# Dart not adding appengine to project package folder

Tags: google-app-engine, dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I just downloaded the latest version of Dart SDK and Editor and tried adding appengine as a dependency like this:

```
    dependencies:
    appengine: ">=0.0.1 <0.1.0"
```

as it was described at https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/appengine

but when I run **pub install**, or **pub get**, it shows **Got dependencies!** but nothing gets added to the package folder, therefore, the following is not working:

```
    import 'package:appengine/appengine.dart';
```

Any idea about what could I be missing?

Thank you.

PS: If I add *browser*, or *polymer*, or any other as a dependency, it works perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### New

It is available 
see https://www.dartlang.org/cloud/ for more details

#### Old

Look at the top right of the site you linked to.

> About
>   Placeholder

This package was published for name reservation purposes only and doesn't contain any code yet.
It is work-in-progress and I hope a useful update will be published soon but I have no detailed knowledge about when this might happen. If [you have seen the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqolCJsvD_g) you might have seen that there is already some working code available (but sadly not yet published).